# Anyone can point me on how to add a dynamic hero image in WordPress using ACF (free version)

Tags: php, dynamic, background-image

I am new to coding and started learning wordpress themes from scratch. I am using ACF the
free version and so far so good. I am following the ACF documentation and i was able to
figure everything out, but i am stock on the image. I want to upload a dynamic hero image,

I try the to implement the code that is provided but i keep getting a broken image in the front end.

HElP!!

Answer (score 0):

1. add new "Field Group"
2. add field to field group with
   "Field Name" => picture
   "Field Type" => "Image"
   and "Return Format" => "Image URL"
3. in "Rules" section connect Field Group to your specific page or post type.
4. save Field Group ("Update" button)
5. go to your page or post and edit. ACF fields will be at the very bottom of the edit form. Select any photo. and publish page/post
6. edit template file of page or post. You can get ACF field by name.

Example:

```
<img src="<?=get_field( "picture" )?>">
```

Comment: Thank you! I am was able to display an image on the frontend but its small it doesn't cover display as a hero banner. do I need to create an a another variable with the sizes?

Comment: Of course you have to use bigger picture :) and maybe correct css and media queries

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to create custom image size,
   https://wpshout.com/wordpress-custom-image-sizes/. If your
   images have already been uploaded don't forget to Regenerate
   Thumbnails for that you will need a separate plugin.
2. Change the return format for your image to 'Image ID'.
3. Use `<img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_field('picture'), 'thumbnail'); ?>" >`, change 'thumbnail' to whatever you named your custom image size.